# Multiple and dynamically loaded CoreML models on demand

Tags: ios, xcode, machine-learning, ios11, coreml

I'm working on an `iOS 11` app to leverage the new CoreML framework. The idea is to have different `.mlmodel` files to handle a video input and provide a user with an ability to choose the desired model to classify it.

I have two issues here:

- unable to add more than one model per xcode project. The xcode stops
  generating strongly typed models and I'm unable to instantiate them
- unable to load `.mlmodel` dynamically (let's say I downloaded it on demand). Is there a way to load `.mlmodel` dynamically?

Comment: 1) I have two sklearn mlmodels in my app and all works fine. What kind of models do you have? 2) There is no good way to load models dynamically, but there is a hacky workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217508/2291058

Comment: When I'm adding two+ models (just two mlmodel files) as part of my project it stops creating classes for them. Any tricks on how to add two+ mlmodels?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bug in Xcode that sometimes prevents code generation when multiple models are present. As a work-around you can set the "CoreML Code Generation Language" in your project settings explicitly (instead of `Automatic`).

As for dynamically loading models: They *just* added a new API with iOS 11 Beta 4 that allows to load models over-the-air and compile them on device now, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel/2921516-compilemodel).

You don't need the generated classes to execute models, you can [initialize them from the compiled model file](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel/2880279-init) yourself with some minor inconvenience. Just inspect the generated classes to see how it's done.

Comment: You can also do both — ship a "dummy" model in your app so you get the nice generated wrapper class, then use the new API to download a trained model that has the same interface. The generated class has an `init(contentsOf:)` initializer so you can use that class with an MLModel file loaded from elsewhere.

Comment: @rickster You really don't have to do that. Just check out the code that is generated for you and build you own wrapper class (you could even copy it exactly). There's no need to ship a dummy model for that.